# MySQL SELECT Query to measure property availability with overlapping availabilities

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of property availability which has 3 relevant columns; property_id, start_date and end_date.

I wrote a query to sum the days available for each property which looks like this:

```
select
property_id,
    sum(greatest(datediff(least(end_date, CURDATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY),start_date),0)) as 30_Day_Avail, 
    sum(greatest(datediff(least(end_date, CURDATE() + INTERVAL 60 DAY),start_date),0)) as 60_Day_Avail,
    sum(greatest(datediff(least(end_date, CURDATE() + INTERVAL 120 DAY),start_date),0)) as 120_Day_Avail, 
    sum(greatest(datediff(least(end_date, CURDATE() + INTERVAL 180 DAY),start_date),0)) as 180_Day_Avail   
from availabilities where start_date >= now()
group by property_id
```

The issue is that the vagaries of our system mean that a property can, in a few cases, have multiple 'availability records' that cover the same day!

[image: Multiple Availabilities]

This means that simply summing the days doesn't product the correct answer!

What I really need is some kind of 'inner query' that iterates over days to establish if the availability count of that property is greater than zero for that date then sums those dates where it is greater than zero.

Comment: I'm sure you can do that in one query (even if I do not yet know how), but wouldn't it be easier to code a user defined function which gets the property_id as input and returns the sum of available days?

Comment: Sorry Alex, I don't quite understand what you mean. My aim is basically to roll individual properties up into Destinations/Countries so I can analyse overall availability.

Comment: ... Why have you allowed your data to look like this?  What purpose does this serve?  Note that queries that first "normalize" this will be expensive.  Or is it that there's subdivisions per `property_id` which might be available on different days (in which case your `SUM()` is actually correct, just not measuring what you thought)?  You should at least add `AND start_date < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 180 DAY` to your `WHERE` clause

Comment: @Clockwork - its a reasonable question! Basically the data is straight from the production DB and its a well intentioned attempt to improve the user experience - when the host updates their calendar, the only records that are removed are those which interfere with the changes meaning that when new records are created they can conflict with existing ones! No sub divisions and I have added the 'AND start_date < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 180 DAY'. Thank You.

Comment: You'd be better off removing/condensing the conflicting rows, then.  It's your application's job to translate from what the user sees to what the db stores (and vice versa).  There's no good reason to allow inconsistencies in your db, especially for things like the first/last two rows of your sample db.  Cleanup your db, it'll save you major headaches in the long run.  For one thing, you're likely to end up updating a row you don't expect at some point...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this setup:

```
drop table if exists c;
create table c (a integer, z integer);
insert into c (a,z) values (1,2),(1,4),(2,3),(2,5),(7,8);

+------+------+
| a    | z    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |
|    1 |    4 |
|    2 |    3 |
|    2 |    5 |
|    7 |    8 |
+------+------+
```

Now compute for each line the maximum z which belongs to an interval in which a falls:

```
select a,z,
(select max(z) from c as righter where righter.a between c.a and c.z) as upper_limit
from c

+------+------+-------------+
| a    | z    | upper_limit |
+------+------+-------------+
|    1 |    2 |           5 |
|    1 |    4 |           5 |
|    2 |    3 |           5 |
|    2 |    5 |           5 |
|    7 |    8 |           8 |
+------+------+-------------+
```

and fetch of each group the minimum a and the maximum z:

```
select min(a) as lower_limit,upper_limit, upper_limit-min(a) as available
from 
    (select a,z,
      (select max(z) from c as righter where righter.a between c.a and c.z) as upper_limit
    from c
    ) aggregates
group by upper_limit

+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| lower_limit | upper_limit | available |
+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|           1 |           5 |         4 |
|           7 |           8 |         1 |
+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Take this is a model to apply on your setup.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/184f3/1

Comment: Thanks Alex, will take a look now!

Comment: Alex, the bit I don't get is in the second step, how does it know that the upper_limit is 5 for the first row? The reason this is important is that I have multiple properties that I am trying to do this for and need to be able to group accordingly!!

Comment: Alex, thanks for you help! Didn't quite get me there but close enough!

Answer (score 1):

There were still a some flaws with my first answer. Please reconsider this:

```
drop table if exists c;
create table c (property integer, a integer, z integer );
INSERT INTO `c` VALUES (1, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO `c` VALUES (1, 1, 4);
INSERT INTO `c` VALUES (1, 2, 3);
INSERT INTO `c` VALUES (1, 2, 5);
INSERT INTO `c` VALUES (1, 7, 8);
INSERT INTO `c` VALUES (2, 1, 4);
INSERT INTO `c` VALUES (2, 2, 5);
INSERT INTO `c` VALUES (2, 3, 6);
INSERT INTO `c` VALUES (2, 2, 7);
INSERT INTO `c` VALUES (2, 22, 44);

+----------+------+------+
| property | a    | z    |
+----------+------+------+
|        1 |    1 |    2 |
|        1 |    1 |    4 |
|        1 |    2 |    3 |
|        1 |    2 |    5 |
|        1 |    7 |    8 |
|        2 |    1 |    4 |
|        2 |    2 |    5 |
|        2 |    3 |    6 |
|        2 |    2 |    7 |
|        2 |   22 |   44 |
+----------+------+------+
select property, lower_margin, upper_margin, upper_margin - lower_margin + 1 as available 
from 
(select *,
    (select min(a) from c as lefter 
    where lefter.property = c.property
    and   (c.a between lefter.a and lefter.z
    or    c.z between lefter.a and lefter.z)

    ) as lower_margin,

    (select max(z) from c as righter 
    where righter.property = c.property
    and   (c.a between righter.a and righter.z
    or    c.z between righter.a and righter.z)
    ) as upper_margin
from c

) x
group by property, lower_margin, upper_margin;


+----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
| property | lower_margin | upper_margin | available |
+----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
|        1 |            1 |            5 |         5 |
|        1 |            7 |            8 |         2 |
|        2 |            1 |            7 |         7 |
|        2 |           22 |           44 |        23 |
+----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
```

In other words: for each start or end date, compute the lowest or highest date respectively of the period in which this start or end date falls. Group them on property and period and fetch the maximum and minimum of each of those groups.

**EDIT:**
To sum the availabe days by property, wrap the query in another grouping query:

```
select property, sum(available) from 

(
select property, lower_margin, upper_margin, upper_margin - lower_margin + 1 as available 
from 
(select *,
    (select min(a) from c as lefter 
    where lefter.property = c.property
    and   (c.a between lefter.a and lefter.z
    or    c.z between lefter.a and lefter.z)

    ) as lower_margin,

    (select max(z) from c as righter 
    where righter.property = c.property
    and   (c.a between righter.a and righter.z
    or    c.z between righter.a and righter.z)
    ) as upper_margin
from c

) x
group by property, lower_margin, upper_margin
) y

group by property;
```

Result:

```
+----------+----------------+
| property | sum(available) |
+----------+----------------+
|        1 |              7 |
|        2 |             30 |
+----------+----------------+
```

Comment: Looks good. How do I then aggregate the available column by 'property'? Using a sum() doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want for your "inner query".   I thought the main issue is to flatten out the data so there are no overlaps, so I tried to do that.  (Fiddle here:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a1872/5 - note that I added some rows to the fiddle dataset, to do a bit of further testing):

```
SELECT
          property_id,
          start_date,
          MAX(end_date) AS end_date
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
            property_id,
            (SELECT MIN(start_date) FROM availabilities WHERE a.property_id = property_id AND a.start_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date) AS start_date,
            (SELECT MAX(end_date) FROM availabilities WHERE a.property_id = property_id AND a.start_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date) AS end_date
  FROM
            availabilities a
  WHERE
            start_date >= NOW()
) t1
GROUP BY
          property_id,
          start_date;
```

This query (with the augmented dataset) produces:

```
PROPERTY_ID    START_DATE                      END_DATE
196873         June, 08 2014 00:00:00+0000      April, 15 2017 00:00:00+0000
196873         April, 18 2017 00:00:00+0000     April, 19 2017 00:00:00+0000
```

I'm not sure what you are expecting in your output, so I couldn't produce for you, but hopefully this can help you out a bit.  There was also a dilemma I had about whether to display the MIN(start_date) for the range or the current date if the current date fell within a start_date and end_date range, but I think you can handle that with well placed CASE statements if need be.  Anyway, hope it helps a bit.

**Edit:** Oops, forgot to add the property_id constraint in my subqueries because it was just one unique one in the dataset.  Have updated my fiddle link as well.

Comment: Thanks - will take a look when I get a few mins. The ultimate goal is to sum the days available for each property to get a summary of total availability.

Comment: No worries.  Just a thought, but for some reason I think you want your WHERE clause to be NOW() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date, instaed of start_date >= NOW().  If start_date and end_date were June 1 2014 and June 30 2014, repspectively, and you run the query June 2, you wouldn't get that row, but I think you'd want it.  Just saying.  Good luck.